# Recognising # symbol within Python Code as Code Not Comment

Tags: python, hash, tcp, tcpclient

I am currently putting some code together to create a TCP/IP client which will have to communicate with an existing network server (Local not Internet). The server code is out of my control as it is already in place. I seem to have test code that works, at least the server recognises that a client with the relevant IP address is making a connection, however, on first connection the server sends out an Identify command to confirm the client is valid:

```
IDENTIFY_#
```

This is my problem. The client code has to be written in Python and obviously #'s seem to create an issue. My understanding (being new to Python) is that they are only used for comments and all of the posts and books I have read seem to say the same. Unfortunately I have to respond with strings that also possess #'s as termination characters for data sets so it makes things twice as problematic. Is it possible to get Python to recognise a # for what it is and not throw a wobbly because it assumes it is a comment?

Comment: `print '#'`.  Can you post some example of the problem you get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the # symbol is within a string literal, it shouldn't be interpreted as a comment.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clearing it up for me, I have now got the socket working just as I wanted and can identify the various commands coming through.